# Scrolling message using just CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a scrolling important message (I don't particularly like them, but clients have requirements!). Ideally I'd like to avoid JavaScript for this, but I'm not sure that's going to be possible.

So far I have a few options, all of which have flaws.

The first 2 in the divs with the class "alert" scroll at different speeds (the longer the message the faster it scrolls). Whats more, if the message is shorter than the container, it starts the animation from the middle of the container.

The last 2 (with class "alert_x") scroll at the same speed but the logic is wrong because the animation is based on the viewport width rather than the message width.

Is there any way to ensure the messages scroll to and from the correct places (from the right of container to the left) and at the same speed no matter what the size of the message - preferably without using JavaScript?

If JS is needed then jQuery is not an option.

```css
.alert {
  height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #00B5D9;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.alert p {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-animation: scroll-left 10s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: scroll-left 10s linear infinite;
  animation: scroll-left 10s linear infinite;
}


/* Move it (define the animation) */

@-moz-keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    /* Browser bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    /* Browser bug fix */
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    /* Browser bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    /* Browser bug fix */
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.alert_x {
  height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #00B5D9;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.alert_x p {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-transform: translateX(calc(100vw));
  -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(100vw));
  transform: translateX(calc(100vw));
  -moz-animation: scroll-left-x 10s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: scroll-left-x 10s linear infinite;
  animation: scroll-left-x 10s linear infinite;
}


/* Move it (define the animation) */

@-moz-keyframes scroll-left-x {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(calc(100vw));
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(calc(100vw * -1));
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll-left-x {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(100vw));
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(100vw * -1));
  }
}

@keyframes scroll-left-x {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(calc(100vw));
    /* Browser bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(100vw));
    /* Browser bug fix */
    transform: translateX(calc(100vw));
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(calc(100vw * -1));
    /* Browser bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(100vw * -1));
    /* Browser bug fix */
    transform: translateX(calc(100vw * -1));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <p>
    Short message
  </p>
</div>

<div class="alert">
  <p>
    Long message... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
  </p>
</div>


<div class="alert_x">
  <p>
    Short message
  </p>
</div>

<div class="alert_x">
  <p>
    Long message... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
  </p>
</div>
```

View on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e31jb7mf/).

**EDIT!**

OK, so I've found a better option which takes a similar approach. It solves all the problems except the fact that the speed differs depending on the length of message.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes ticker {
  0% {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
visibility: visible;
  }
  
  100% {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes ticker {
  0% {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
visibility: visible;
  }
  
  100% {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

.alert-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: teal;
  padding-left: 100%;
}

.alert {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: ticker;
  animation-name: ticker;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-duration: 30s;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert-wrap">
<div class="alert">
    <div>Long message... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Long message... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Long message... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if I do, is this the kind of thing you are looking for:

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}

p {
transform: translateX(100vw);
white-space: nowrap;
animation: scrollLeft 15s linear infinite; 
}

@keyframes scrollLeft {
0% {transform: translateX(100vw);}
100% {transform: translateX(-375vw);}
}
```

```html
<p>Tiny message.</p>
<p>This is a short message.</p>
<p>This is something which at least approaches a medium length message.</p>
<p>This is, as you can see, a rather longer message which takes up a lot more space and is certainly visually longer than the preceding three messages.</p>
<p>This is an absolutely enormous message which seems to go on and on forever and never really looks like it's going to end and you start to wonder if it might actually go on infinitely but then, eventually, almost unexpectedly it does, finally... wait for it... suggest that it might stop... before it actually continues a little more and then, reluctantly does indeed, finally come to an end.</p>
```

---

## Second Attempt

Now that I've got a better grasp of what the intended effect is, I've gone for a javascript approach (using `CSSOM`). I've got most of the way there, but I'm stuck on trying to get all the messages to scroll at the same speed.

As it is:

- the messages all begin at the same place at the same time
- the messages all end at the same place at the same time (and then restart)

But, predictably, that means the messages aren't all moving at the same speed - the longer messages are moving faster than the shorter messages in order to complete their scrolling animation at the same time.

**Working Example:**

```js
const paragraphs = [... document.getElementsByTagName('p')];

paragraphs.forEach(function(paragraph){
paragraph.dataset.width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(paragraph).getPropertyValue('width')) + 12;

const stylesheet = document.styleSheets[(document.styleSheets.length - 1)];
stylesheet.insertRule('[data-width="' + paragraph.dataset.width + '"]{animation: scrollLeft_' + paragraph.dataset.width + ' ' + ((paragraph.dataset.width + window.innerWidth) / ((paragraph.dataset.width + window.innerWidth) / 20)) + 's linear infinite;}', stylesheet.cssRules.length);
stylesheet.insertRule('@keyframes scrollLeft_' + paragraph.dataset.width + '{0%{transform: translateX(100vw);} 100%{transform: translateX(calc(0vw - ' + paragraph.dataset.width + 'px));}}', stylesheet.cssRules.length);

});
```

```css
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}

p {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
clear: left;
padding: 6px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
border-radius: 3px;
transform: translateX(100vw);
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p>Tiny message.</p>
<p>This is a short message.</p>
<p>This is something which at least approaches a medium length message.</p>
<p>This is, as you can see, a rather longer message which takes up a lot more space and is certainly visually longer than the preceding three messages.</p>
<p>This is an absolutely enormous message which seems to go on and on forever and never really looks like it's going to end and you start to wonder if it might actually go on infinitely but then, eventually, almost unexpectedly it does, finally... wait for it... suggest that it might stop... before it actually continues a little more and then, reluctantly does indeed, finally come to an end.</p>
```

Comment: If the longer message in your example is say 4 times longer, then the message doesn't finish scrolling before it starts again.  `100% {transform: translateX(-375vw);}` needs to be dynamic depending on the length of the message

Comment: I've made some progress: each message now scrolls a dynamic distance. But, in my second attempt (above) all the messages now scroll at different speeds in order to finish at the same time and I understand you want to achieve the opposite - that all  messages should scroll at the same speed and finish at different times.